# Insert Into data from other table vb . net access OleDb

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, insert

I have different tables on same database , and i need to insert ID's of data from combobox.
Here's client table

[image]

[image: And here's other table]

[image: here's my app]

what i need is to get id from combobox selected item and put it on the final table,
this is what i try

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Client", client.Text)

Private Sub livbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles livbtn.Click
        'ModePaiement()
        Try
            SQL = "INSERT INTO LIVRAISONCLIENTGNC(Codeclient) SELECT code_client from client WHERE client =  @Client "
            Execute(SQL, "Insert")

            MessageBox.Show("The record has been saved.", "",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            ResetMe()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("" & ex.Message, "",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        End Try

    End Sub
```

and not working for sure , please help !

here's Module data connection:

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Module AccessDB_Connection

    Public Function GetConnectionString() As String
        Dim strCon As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\BLdatabase.accdb;Persist Security Info = false;"
        Return strCon
    End Function

    Public con As New OleDbConnection(GetConnectionString())
    Public cmd As OleDbCommand
    Public SQL As String = String.Empty

    Public Function PerformCRUD(Com As OleDbCommand) As DataTable
        Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim dt As New DataTable()

        Try
            da = New OleDbDataAdapter
            da.SelectCommand = Com
            da.Fill(dt)
            Return dt
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("" & ex.Message)

        End Try
        Return dt
    End Function

End Module
```

Comment: What does the method `Execute` look like?  If you are using OleDb, take a look at the parameterized queries, @ is used for SQL Server and ? is used for MS Access: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: There's no description of your actual issue in this question. You need to be SPECIFIC. Is `client` your `ComboBox`? Is `client.Text` the ID you want? Please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the issue.

Comment: You need to show use the Execute method, and explain what isn't working.  Are you getting errors or unexpected results. and what are they?  Also seems like some iffy db design going on there.  Shouldn't you be using Client_Code in Livraisonclientgnc rather than the CodeClient, your data doesn't even seem to be unique. And what's the point of selecting the record from Client when it's going to give you the exact same value as just inserting the value from your combo?

Comment: @Pete-S-, you can still use names prefixed with "@" for Access. The Jet and ACE providers use positional parameters so you must make sure that you add them in the correct order and you cannot use the same parameter twice, but it's still a good idea to use names to make things easier to read. For instance, if you use names then it's easy to see whether the parameters are in the wrong order.

Comment: Just to clarify on jmc's *cannot use the same parameter twice*, [with ACE12 at least] you *can* use the same `@parameter` twice in the SQL but value assignment is still positional based on a left-to-right scan of the SQL for unique parameter names. `SELECT * FROM person WHERE firstName= @n OR age = @a OR lastName = @n` needs `AddWithValue("dontcare", "Lee")` `AddWithValue("dontcare", 20)` and will find anyone with a first or last name of Lee or age of 20.

Comment: The .net side parameter names are irrelevant to the query but if you want to access the collection by name you should make them unique, and they must be added in the order that the unique names appear in the SQL so an SQL of `WHERE age = @a OR first = @n or last = @n` needs `AddWithValue(.. 20)`, `AddWithValue(.. "Lee")`  because the distinct-keeping-only-first-occurrence parameter names appear in `@a` then `@n` order in the SQL

Answer (score 0):

thank's everybody for replying;
so here's execute method :

```
Private Sub Execute(MySQL As String, Optional Parameter As String = "")
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(MySQL, con)
    AddParameters(Parameter)
    PerformCRUD(cmd)
End Sub

 Private Sub AddParameters(str As String)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Client", client.Text)
End Sub

    Public Function PerformCRUD(Com As OleDbCommand) As DataTable
        Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim dt As New DataTable()

        Try
            da = New OleDbDataAdapter
            da.SelectCommand = Com
            da.Fill(dt)
            Return dt
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("" & ex.Message)

        End Try
        Return dt
    End Function
```

so it's very simple , i need to store an id value from an selected item :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOoVI.png)

here's an example , i need to store that value 26 from that table client to other table when i select IMAX client from combobox
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNZoV.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/993Eq.png)

there's 2 different results it depends on the query used :
with  SQL = "INSERT INTO LIVRAISONCLIENTGNC(Codeclient) SELECT code_client from client WHERE client =  @Client " --> there's nothing happened
with             SQL = "INSERT INTO LIVRAISONCLIENTGNC(Codeclient) values(SELECT code_client from client WHERE client =  @Client) "
--> error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2NU1.png)

Answer (score 0):

The issue I see, you are trying to run:

```
 SQL = "INSERT INTO LIVRAISONCLIENTGNC(Codeclient) SELECT code_client from client WHERE client =  @Client "
```

However, in your PerformCRUD method, you are filling a data adapter and returning a `DataTable` based on an INSERT where `ExecuteNoQuery` is the method to use.

Here is an example ([More Info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter?view=netframework-4.8)):

```
Using cmd = con.CreateCommand()
     cmd.CommandText = SQL
    'It is good practice to specify the data type. Note: 80 in this example is the column size/length.
    cmd.Parameter.Add("@Client", OleDbType.VarChar, 80).Value = client.Text
    cmd.Connection = con
    con.Open() 'if not already open
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

Comment: S- , thanks for replying , but i think this method is useful on SqlConnection but i'm using OleDbConnection

Comment: @houcemabidi, it's similar for both.  Take a look at this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: look at this , i add this part of code at button_click method but it show me error on Using cmd = New con.CreateCommand()  Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error BC30002 Type 'con.CreateCommand' is not defined. WindowsApp2 C:\Users\Houssem-Abidi\Documents\Bon de livraison\LVRCLT\WindowsApp2\WindowsApp2\Form2.vb 102 Active

Comment: @houcemabidi: can you edit your original post and show me how you are creating your con (connection)?

Comment: I removed the New from using... (not needed).  [CreateCommand][1] is a method of the Connection object.  


  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.createcommand?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: there's other error on  cmd.Parameter.Add                                                                                        Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error BC30456 'Parameter' is not a member of 'OleDbCommand'. WindowsApp2 C:\Users\Houssem-Abidi\Documents\Bon de livraison\LVRCLT\WindowsApp2\WindowsApp2\Form2.vb 107 Active

Comment: it's working now , i had change it with this cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Client", client.Text) , but now i want to get more id like clientID ,

Comment: it's working now , i had change it with this cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Client", client.Text) , but now i want to get more id like clientID ,  so should i use this query                                                          SQL = "INSERT INTO LIVRAISONCLIENTGNC(DateLVRclient,DateEcheanceLVRclient,RemarqueLVRclient,Client,Nomclient,Representantclient,Affaireclient,ReferenceAffaireLVRclient) VALUES(@DateLivr,@DateEch,@Remarque,@Client,@Nom,@Representant,@Affaire,@Reference)"

Comment: @houcemabidi, yes, that should work.  You define the parameter, add it to the parameter's collection.  Best of luck!